# Maven assembly plugin - "install" folder

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have configured maven assembly plugin which generates "tar.gz" file.

However, when I untar, it somehow includes "install" folder at the beginning:

```
/install/lib
/install/scripts
```

My requirement is that, upon untar, it should have folders like below, **no install directory**:

```
/lib
/scripts
```

My pom.xml plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>install</finalName>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly/app-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

app-assembly.xml:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>myapp</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>src/**</exclude>
                <exclude>readme.md</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Appreciate any help or guidance on this. Thanks for reading.

Comment: can you post your assembly plugin configuration from pom.xml?

Comment: Please post your pom file and the assembly descriptor...

Comment: @DipakPawar and khmarbaise - Updated original post with pom and assembly code.

Comment: Can please add which versions of Maven and Maven Assembly plugin you are using? BTW: Do you have a `install` directory in your root area of your project?

Answer (score 0):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

**includeBaseDirectory**: Includes a base directory in the final archive. For example, if you are creating an assembly named "your-app", setting includeBaseDirectory to true will create an archive that includes this base directory. If this option is set to false the archive created will unzip its content to the current directory.
Default value is: true.